# Find numbers from Mean, Variance and Correlation coefficient

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

I have a set of numbers $A=\lbrace a_1,a_2,a_3,...a_n \rbrace$

I want to find new numbers    $X=\lbrace x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_n \rbrace$ such

1. [Mean](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PopulationMean.html)

$$\mu(A )=\mu(X)$$

2. [Variance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Variance.html)

   $$Var(A)=Var(X)$$
3. [Correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)  $$r_{AX}=k $$

Where $k$ is a some constant, $0<k<1$ .

each number $x_1(k),x_2(k)...x_n(k)$  depends only $k$,

How to solve this system of equations by using *Mathematica*?

for instance, $A=\lbrace 2,5,7 \rbrace$

and $k=0.7$

How to find $x_1,x_2,x_3?$

I tried first few steps:

$1.$

```
list = {2,5,7}
X= {l, m, n}

Mean[list]
```

> $\frac{14}{3}$

```
Mean[X]
```

> $\frac{1}{3} (l+m+n)$

$2.$

```
Variance[list]
```

> $\frac{19}{5}$

```
Refine[Variance[X], x \[Element] Reals]
```

> $\frac{1}{6} (l (2 l-m-n)+m (-l+2 m-n)+n
>    (-l-m+2 n))$

Comment: [A related CV thread.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30303)

Comment: As @J.M. notes, the linked question shows it's trivial to generate a set of numbers with a given mean and variance, but the tricky part here is getting the correlation to be exactly what you want. You could try randomly generating until you get close?

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, this is just a system of equations, so we can use `Solve` to get solutions for the values of $X$:

```
list = {2, 5, 7};
X = {l, m, n};
k = .7;
Assuming[Element[X, Reals], Solve[Mean[list] == Mean[X] && 
    Simplify[Variance[list] == Variance[X]]] && Simplify[Correlation[list, X] == k], {l, m, n}]
```

`Correlation` is the Pearson correlation coefficient which ranges between -1 and 1, if you mean something else you can just use a different function for that.

If you only need to do this for sets with 3 elements as in your example this should do the trick.  If there are also longer ones of the form {$a_1$, $a_2$,...,$a_n$} there is no unique solution since you have more unknowns than equations and you should be able to do something like choose random values for $n-3$ of the values in $X$ and then use `Solve` for the last 3.

Comment: thanks. but for example if `list = {49, 25, 26, 5, 21, 47, 24}` and `x = {4, 6, 3, 1, l, m, t}`  and `k=0.7` there is no real solution. How to choose $n-3$ random number to get a real solution?